# can not add new line in yaml file that contains space in key name with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have yaml file

```
---
a:
  b:
    c: C
  d d:
    e: E
```

I try to do add `f: F` in `d d` index like this:

```
---
a:
  b:
    c: C
  d d:
    e: E
    f: F
```

with this command:

```
$ yq -i '.a."d d" += {"f": "F"}' file.yaml
```

and got this error

```
Error: 1:7: invalid input text "d\" += {\"f\": \"F\"}"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding `[]`.

solution:

```
yq -i '.a.["d d"] += {"f": "F"}' file.yaml
```